# Is it professional to quit job after 1 month of 6 months probation

Tags: job-search, new-job, new-hires, probation

I have just started my new job. The company is a really great well-known company to work for (on the benefits perspective), no doubt, but my position itself is not really my expertise. I realize it after first week that it is probably my big mistake that I didn't clarify it during interviews. Of course I knew what they do during interviews, but I haven't expected that it is so different from my 5 years experience in this field (their workflows, team's structures, process management, etc.), and I am feeling that I am not a good fit for them. Of course I could stay with them, but I have a concern that if I should continue the path that I have been doing the last 5 years, or I should really do something new.

Anyway, I have decided that I will look for a new position. I know, it is not nice and professional to find a new job after 1 month, but I think it would be good for both parties. My questions are:
- Does it make my picture bad in the company? And how to tell them in the way that doesn't cause any bad consequence? 
- If I have an interview now, should I mention that I am working at the moment for another company?

I am in panic and stress about this predicament I am in. Thanks in advance for your professional advice.

EDIT: The duplicate marked question is different, because the person in the question didn't really a contract.

Comment: Look at a job kind of like a marriage. Do all marriages work out? No. But then think of this: Imagine marrying someone after 2 or 3 dates.  That's what is expected when you hire permanently. That's why I always do contract to perm. Just like I wouldn't marry someone after spending 2 or 3 hours with them and talking to their friends, I'm not going to call a job actually permanent until I've experienced it a bit.  Basically, don't sweat it. Don't do this a lot, but once in a while and people understand. And for me, using the marriage metaphor helps in the next interview.

Comment: Resigning for not a good fit during probation is generally reasonable, but I am concerned for your long term career prospects if you cannot adjust to a new set of workflows, team structures, and process management. Those things vary between organizations, and what is common changes over time.

Comment: I had a collegue that came to my company and then left after a month because it was not a good fit for him. Nothing wrong here, its your duty to pursuit a job where you feel good, not to think what will some random stranger (your boss) think of you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, no need to panic.  A period of adjustment is perfectly normal and expected.  You've come into a brand new environment, and all of a sudden you need to adapt quickly to the way in which the new employer does things.  This can take some time to adjust to.  Months, not weeks in some cases.

Secondly, that probationary period isn't just to determine if you're a good fit for the company, it's also for you to see if the company is a good fit for you.  So, if you decide you want to leave and pursue other options, then you are completely within your remit to want to leave.  I don't see that it would paint you in a bad light, sure you would need to discuss it when asked about it in interviews, but you could easily turn around and say "it wasn't the right choice for me" or something like that.

I was actually in a similar position to you fairly recently.  I left a good role in a small manufacturing plant - IT team of 2, and moved to a big retailer who had an IT staff of over 500 people.  I'd never worked in a big environment before, and felt completely out of my depth.  Totally overwhelmed by everything, so many new processes to learn, and the job hadn't been what I was expecting, and was a bit of a step down too career-wise.  It was a HUGE wrench and probably took me around 3 months to fully feel like I was able to contribute and understand.  I now really enjoy going to work and yes, it's a change to what I was doing but I'm learning new stuff on a daily basis which is helping me to develop further as an IT Professional.

My first suggestion would be, if you have a team leader or manager that is approachable, have a conversation with them about your fears.  Be honest.  If the company is half-decent, they will want to have regular reviews with you about how you feel things are going and if there is anything they can do to help you settle in a bit better.  Speak up and see if there is help, before walking away from what could be a great opportunity.  If you decide to go ahead and move on, then that's ok too - but if you leave on good terms by being open and honest with the new employers about your concerns, that's even better.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I found your situation and mine are the same. I also left a good role in small company and moved to a real big enterprise. Like you said, I am overwhelmed at first, but then I assessed all the working environment, and as I said, I am not sure if it does me any good. I have worked the last 5 years for SaaS, pure Software. But new role is, the company produces hardware measure tools, which have a simple web interface and app to communicate. like, 70% hardware, and 30% software. That goes my concern, as I only worked in Software field ...

Answer (score 3):

> Does it make my picture bad in the company?

No one is ever going to be happy if a new hire leaves after a month: it means there was a failure in the hiring process, on one side, the other or both. But... it's better to leave after a month than to hang around in a job you're not happy with, as that's not a good situation for either your employer or you.

> And how to tell them in the way that doesn't cause any bad consequence?

"Sorry, this isn't the role I thought I was. That was my failure for not clarifying it during the hiring process and I apologise for that, but here's my resignation".

> If I have an interview now, should I mention that I am working at the moment for another company?

You certainly don't lie if asked, and you almost certainly will be asked.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it make my picture bad in the company? And how to tell them in
>   the way that doesn't cause any bad consequence?

These things happen. Most employers understand that.

Probation is all about assessing fit. The company wants to see if you are a good fit for the position. And you want to see if the position fits your needs. You have concluded that it doesn't. Hopefully 1 month is enough time for you to come to that conclusion.

Find a new job. Get and accept an offer. Then tell your current company that it simply hasn't worked out as you had hoped. Then work out your notice period.